# Where should I add type definitions?

Tags: typescript, npm

Currently my `@types/...` are inside dependencies part of `package.json` file.

Should I move `@types/vuelidate` to "devDependencies" from "dependencies"?

For example; how will I know **where does `@types/lodash` belong to?**

Type definitions are needed just during development time, isn't it?

Comment: Put the types for development time dependencies in `"devDepenencies"`. Put the types for runtime dependencies in `"depenencies"`. There are exception to this advice, but it is a good starting point. Elsewise, consumers of your package who are also using TypeScript will have to add @types for all runtime dependencies manually. On the other hand, don't put @types for dev dependencies under `"dependencies"` - no one wants your `@types/node` because bundled a browser library for distribution via webpack.

Comment: Would you please write it in answer form? So I can accept it.

Comment: I'm hesitant to create an answer because there are certain cases where you cannot do as I suggested and because a lot of what I said is depended on opinion. For example, some JavaScript users resent the inclusion of type declaration files in the packages they consume because they don't use them. They resent having to download them. This is a little silly, because most JavaScript tooling today actually read those files anyway but you can see how someone would feel that way